# table view with multiple columns

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad

i want to display name phone number and salary of a employee in an ipad in the form of table with multiple columns for that i take three table views and successfully displayed data in  them . the table views are scrolling independently.but i want to implement if one table view is scrolled the second and third must be moved parallel. can any one please tell me how to implement that one....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all your UITableViews dependants and scrolling at the same time, there is no reason to create multiple table view.

You can just create un custom UITableViewCell with the layout and style you want! This will be easier and will consume less resources.

Answer (score 0):

find out position of cell in first table depending on that change position of cell in next table.
You can use following property of UITableView - – scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: